# How to use javascript function in just fixed numbers of time?

Tags: javascript, function

```
<img src='plus.jpg' width='80' height='80' onclick="myFunction2()">
```

return

```
function myFunction2() {
        var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
        x.setAttribute("name", "image[]");
        x.setAttribute("type", "file");
        document.getElementById("add").appendChild(x);
}
```

I would like to use myFunction2() just 4 times.
After that, I want to stop this function.
Can you give me any suggestion?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about using a looping statement?

Comment: I did but I don't know exactly where to put the index number... @RajaprabhuAravindasamy

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: Thank you!! @RajaprabhuAravindasamy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
var limit = 1;
function myFunction2() {
  if(limit <= 4){
   var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
   x.setAttribute("name", "image[]");
   x.setAttribute("type", "file");
   document.getElementById("add").appendChild(x);
   limit += 1;
  }else{
   alert("Stop");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @MohammaeAbed

Answer (score 1):

solution using jQuery.

```
var timesClicked = 0;
$( "#imgId" ).bind( "click", function( event ) {

  // do your operations here

  timesClicked++;
  if ( timesClicked >= 4 ) {
    $( this ).unbind( event );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use a counter to check when the clicks reach 4, like this

**HTML:**

```
<img src='plus.jpg' width='80' height='80' onclick="myFunction2()">
```

**INTO JS**

```
    var myCounter=0;  
    function myFunction2() {
if(myCounter <4){myCounter++;
            var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
            x.setAttribute("name", "image[]");
            x.setAttribute("type", "file");
            document.getElementById("add").appendChild(x);
}
    }
```